# Upload destination folder configuration problem in Symfony 6 with oneup/uploader-bundle and oneup/flysystem-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6, uppy, oneupuploaderbundle

### Introduction

In personal project I am using `Symfony v6.3` with:

- `oneup/uploader-bundle` ([v4.0.1](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle))
- `oneup/flysystem-bundle` ([v4.9.0](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle))

for upload on client side I have chosen:

- `Uppy` ([v3.15.0](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy))

---

### Prerequisites

I need to have 2 separate folders for 2 types of uploads:

- First for regular uploads in the chosen folder (up to 10 files in one go) and
- second for temporary uploads that are used when replacing files one by one (1 file at a time).

I have 2 uploaders `uppy_many` and `uppy_one`, both upload to local folder on the server.

---

### The problem

I am setting 2 zones up in config files, but it does not work as i need.

TLDR - only the last declaration in the config is in effect (all uploads go to last declared zone).

I might have a configuration problem or an edge case bug.

---

### The code

> relevant part or services.yml

UPPY many (services.yml)

```
    app.upload_many_listener:
        class: App\EventListener\UploadManyListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.pre_upload.uppy_many, method: onPreUpload }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_upload.uppy_many, method: onPostUpload }
    
    app.upload_many_validation_listener:
        class: App\EventListener\UploadManyValidationListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.validation.uppy_many, method: onValidate }
    
    app.upload_many_unique_namer:
        class: App\Uploader\Naming\UploadManyUniqueNamer
        public: true
```

UPPY one (services.yml)

```
    app.upload_one_listener:
        class: App\EventListener\UploadOneListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.pre_upload.uppy_one, method: onPreUpload }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_upload.uppy_one, method: onPostUpload }
    
    app.upload_one_validation_listener:
        class: App\EventListener\UploadOneValidationListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.validation.uppy_one, method: onValidate }
    
    app.upload_one_unique_namer:
        class: App\Uploader\Naming\UploadOneUniqueNamer
        public: true
```

FlySystem (services.yml)

```
    oneup_flysystem.uppy_many_filesystem:
        alias: League\Flysystem\Filesystem
        public: true
    oneup_flysystem.uppy_one_filesystem:
        alias: League\Flysystem\Filesystem
        public: true
```

> oneup_uploader.yml

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
    
        uppy_many:
            frontend: custom
            custom_frontend:
                class: App\Controller\Uppy\CustomManyUploader
                name: uppy_many
            storage:
                type: flysystem
                filesystem: oneup_flysystem.uppy_many_filesystem
            enable_progress: true
            namer: app.upload_many_unique_namer
            
        uppy_one:
            frontend: custom
            custom_frontend:
                class: App\Controller\Uppy\CustomOneUploader
                name: uppy_one
            storage:
                type: flysystem
                filesystem: oneup_flysystem.uppy_one_filesystem
            enable_progress: true
            namer: app.upload_one_unique_namer
```

> oneup_flysystem.yml

```
oneup_flysystem:

    adapters:
        uppy_many_adapter:
            local:
                location: '%data_dir_stored%'
        uppy_one_adapter:
            local:
                location: '%data_dir_temporary%'

    filesystems:
        uppy_many_filesystem:
            adapter: uppy_many_adapter
            alias: League\Flysystem\Filesystem
        uppy_one_filesystem:
            adapter: uppy_one_adapter
            alias: League\Flysystem\Filesystem

        # only the last declaration of filesystem takes an effect
        # at the moment both uploaders (many and one) upload to `temporary`
```

---

### P.S.

Please advise, thank you!